# How to access to Entity Bean from remote client?

Tags: java, mysql, entity, javabeans, wildfly

I have a Java EE project accessing a MySQL database through WildFly. In the EJB I have an Entity (`Book`) and a Session Bean (`BookBean`) that exposes methods to manage the database from within a Remote Client.

If I have a method `getAllBooks()` that, for example, has return type `List<Book>`, that is, it returns a list of all the books in the databases, how does the client know about the Entity?

The EJB implements a Remote Interface placed in the Client (`BookBeanRemote`), so the latter must know about the Entity since the method has return type `List<Book>`. This approach is very bad, since it means both the client and the server must know everything about the Entity.

I know I should use Session Facades and Service Locators, but I am unable to find a good updated tutorial explaining how they work and how to use them in a simple example.

As explained [here](http://Use%20a%20session%20bean%20as%20a%20facade%20to%20encapsulate%20the%20complexity%20of%20interactions%20between%20the%20business%20objects%20participating%20in%20a%20workflow.%20The%20Session%20Facade%20manages%20the%20business%20objects,%20and%20provides%20a%20uniform%20coarse-grained%20service%20access%20layer%20to%20clients.), Session Facades exposes everything to the Client without adding complexity. Could you provide an example using Session Facades? My client is a simple Java Class. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does the client know about the entity? Hopefully the client has it in its classpath, or otherwise there's going to be problems.

Comment: In order to test if the connection to the database was correct, I just copied the entity file in the Client package. However, of course, this is NOT a valid approach. I'd like to know how to use Session Facades to accomplish this.

Comment: Why is it not a valid approach?

Comment: It is not a valid approach because it requires you to duplicate code: i.e., you have the Entity file both in the client and in the server, and this may be not possible. Additionally, every time you change something in the Server, you need to update the Client as well, so definitely it is not a good approach. 
Some time ago I was using RMI to pass the code between Client and Server, but I don't think it is feasible in this case.

Additionally, we are speaking of clients and servers running on different machines.

Comment: Yeah, there's definitely downsides, as things often do. However saying this is **NOT** a valid approach is taking things a bit too far. I also fail to see why you'd need to update the client every time you change something in the server. If `Book` is the only thing shared, why would you update the client unless you change `Book`?

Comment: In this way you still need a RemoteInterface (implemented by the bean in the server) in the client. Plus, you need a file for each Entity. Should the code change in the future, you'd have to update every client manually. I really do not think this is a good approach.
Also, for this reason there are instruments such as SessionFacades over DAO or DTO: I'd really like if you could give me a simple example with some basic updated code.

Comment: A simple example of what? You asked how the client knows about the entity, and I answered it. Then you started complaining and now I've lost all interest in this question.

Comment: If you don't want to provide an example with Session Facades, that's okay, there's no reason to be upset. I do simply know my approach with plenty of redundant code over potentially thousands of remote clients is WRONG, so I'd like to know how to improve it. By the way, I'm sorry if the question was not clear, I've updated it.

Comment: If you're using a façade, there won't **be** a `Book` class on the client side. I think you've misunderstood something.

Comment: That's exactly my point. I'd like to change my code in order to not use the Book class on the client side. The problem is, I really can't find a code example on how to accomplish this: I found dozens of tutorials speaking about how you SHOULD do that, explaining structure and patterns, but no actual code.

Comment: Then Google for examples and write clearer questions in the future.

Comment: I have already googled, but no luck. Tutorials use either old EJB 2.1 (and I really don't use that) or web applications.